# Article layout override in J!4

Tags: component, articles, template-override, joomla-4.x, upgrade

I'm starting to worry about updating my Joomla! 3 to Joomla! 4 (4.0.6 at the time of posting this).

In Joomla!, 3 I used a lot the functionality that allows to create article layout overrides by duplicating and renaming the files located in `components/com_content/views/article/tmpl` to the html folder of my custom themes (often created from the [Bl4nk Blogger Schmidt template based on Bootstrap 4](https://github.com/Bloggerschmidt/Blank-Bootstrap-Edition)).

Then, by adding beside copied and renamed files, the updated xml file, the personalized layout becomes available from the component menu Article.
See paragraph n°7 of the J!3 doc which has been my reference for a long time: `https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Layout_...ive_Menu_Items`

I tried to reproduce this method in Joomla! 4, but if I can select article override in the Article component menu (the reference appears well in the list as for example `COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_VIEW_HERO_TITLE`), this override does not seem to be taken into account in the frontend. The default article layout still seems to be used.

Can I still keep working this way in Joomla! 4?

Comment: The links in your question appear to be broken to me, you may like to update them.

Comment: Sorry for that. Here are the correct links:
[link](https://github.com/Bloggerschmidt/Blank-Bootstrap-Edition) and [link](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla#Alternative_Menu_Items)